# cf-agent Error: "Unexpected argument with no preceding option"

Tags: cfengine

I've installed CFEngine on my policy server and host, according to the documentation here:

https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.5/getting-started-installation-installing-community.html

When I run the command `/var/cfengine/bin/cf-agent -B 10.0.0.253` to bootstrap my host to the policyserver, I get the error: "Unexpected argument with no preceding option: 10.0.0.253
Fatal CFEngine error: Aborted".

I tried searching around on the web but couldn't find a solid answer.

Anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: I've fixed it. Seems like the CFEngine docs need to be updated. The correct command is `/var/cfengine/bin/cf-agent -B -s 10.0.0.253`

Answer (score 0):

You must have an older version installed. Bootstrapping used to require `-B -s <IP>` then it was shortened to `-B <ip>`.